# Q20. What is the order of execution of the lines of the following program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, multiple-choice, order-of-execution

Q20. What is the order of execution of the lines of the following program?

```
def f1(x): #1
 temp = x + 1 #2
 return temp #3
def f2(y): #4
 t = y -1 #5
 v = f1(t) #6
 return v #7
 #8
print(f2(5)) #9
```

Answers (choose one):
a) 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-9
b) 1-4-9-4-5-6-1-2-3-6-7-9
c) 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-9-4-5-6-7
d) 1-4-9-4-5-6-1-2-3-6
e) None of the above
Here they say that the answer is e (none of the above) but im not sure what would be the correct order that python would execute these lines. how would i know for each different function ?

Comment: `9-4-5-6-1-2-3-7-9`

Comment: Functions don't get executed until they are called. You could argue the definition lines are executed when they are defined, so I'd say the order is `1-4-9-5-6-2-3-7`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi don't know i'm correct or not but when `9th line` execute the parameter `5` first initialize to `y` which is in the line `4` .. is it correct?

Comment: I recommend stepping through the code with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

In your code there are `2 functions` these `2 functions` run when it will call so first the line 9 execute which calls `f2` function it will run till `#6` line and than the `f2` function calling another function `f1` now `f1` function will start to execute till end than comes to the `f2` intialize `v` and then execute `7th` line which is returning and than finally it will print the statement..!

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the key points here by defining a function with a deliberately introduced error. For example,

```
def f(x):
    return squirt
```

Assuming `squirt` is not defined in the global scope (outside the function definition), calling this function would result in the error

```
NameError: name 'squirt' is not defined
```

However, notice that it is perfectly acceptable to *define* the function, with `def f(x)`. This means that the lines of the function are not executed in any way when the line *defining* the function (`def f(x)`) is executed.

Only once the function is *called* are the lines of the function executed (without re-executing the definition).

Another point, it seems somewhat ambiguous to ask when the line is executed, when the line contains a call to another function (e.g. line #6). However, the assignment contained in line#6 cannot actually take place until the value to the right of the assignment expression is evaluated. So you may say that line#6 - an assignment - is executed *after* lines #2 and #3 are executed. Likewise, line#9 cannot be executed until the call to `f2` is resolved.

Taking these points together, and combining with the fact that Python code is read from top to bottom, the answer would be

```
1-4-5-2-3-6-7-9
```